# How to get the full namespace of a module after its imported in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
from foo.bar import bar

print(get_namespace(bar))
```

I want the above code snippet to print the "foo.bar.bar"

How to do it in python3 ?

Comment: Is `bar` a function or a submodule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every imported module is listed in `sys.modules`. So you could iterate through `sys.modules` to find the path associated with the module:

```
import sys
def get_module_name(mod):
    for path, module in sys.modules.items():
        if mod == module:
            return path
    raise ValueError('module not found')


from foo.bar import bar
print(get_module_name(bar))
# foo.bar.bar
```

---

Since the word `namespace` is reserved for [a different concept](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-namespace), I've renamed the function `get_module_name`.